# How to save UITableView state for different Items

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to show a `ViewController` where it has two UIViews, just like finder in Mac.
The left view contains a tableview with items.When user selects an item the right view displays tableView with related data.

So the next requirement is that which ever tableView is shown on the right side is editable for selection of sub items in rows and once the editing is done it should keep its state, so that on selecting the second item and re-selecting the first item, the tableView should show all the selected sub items.

Comment: Just as Filter UIView which is seen on Flipkart app

Answer (score 0):

You can refer - https://www.raywenderlich.com/94443/uisplitviewcontroller-tutorial-getting-started
That is called splitviewcontroller or master detail controller

Comment: i want the funtionality just as Filter View which is seen on Amazon/Flipkart app